# How to grant execution permission on procedure to ALL USERS

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

I need to grant all users with execution permissions to execute `myprocedure`

I'm using this:

```
grant execute on procedure myprocedure to '*'@'%%';
```

And I got this:

```
SQL Error [1410] [42000]: You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT
```

I also tried to create it with root user, but it didn't work:

```
mysql> select user();
+----------------+
| user()         |
+----------------+
| root@localhost |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> grant execute on procedure myprocedure to '*'@'%%';
ERROR 1410 (42000): You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT
mysql>
```

Any idea?

Comment: `.. to '*'@'%%';` - Incorrect user definition. See [Specifying Account Names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/account-names.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/grant.html says:

> *MySQL does not support wildcards in user names.*

(emphasis is theirs)

Users don't get privileges implicitly when they are created.

You must grant privileges to each user explicitly as they are created.

This is a good thing for the sake of security. It would be a bad strategy if users gained privileges that you didn't intend them to have, just because someone set up a GRANT with a wildcard.